# What keeps a swinging rubber ball in a horizontal circle above head from falling?

Tags: centripetal-force

If i swing a rubber ball above my head in a horizontal circle, there will be centripetal motion and force but only in X axis,what keeps the rubber ball from falling since there is only one force acting on the ball in Y axis and that is gravity, why the ball doesn't fall?

Comment: Have you heard about Pseudo force? If yes then you will get your answer without explanation!

Comment: @CreepyCreature ... Pesudo-forces don't really solve anything here.

Comment: See the linked potential duplicate.  Their question wording is a bit different; but it's the same situation.  You noticed something good about the question that is often not explicitly stated; horizontal swinging doesn't really work.  I almost wish I could make the other question a duplicate of this one; the wording here is much clearer and less like a homework question.

Comment: @JMac so basically you can't  swing the ball completely horizental without the ball falling, right?

Comment: @Zheer Yeah; though as soon as it starts to fall you would regain some upwards force.

Comment: @Zheer I can see you swinging the ball below you head. Then if the vertical upward component of the tension in the string equals $mg$, the ball will swing in a horizontal plane without falling. Not sure you can do it over your head. This appears to be a duplicate of "Why doesn't a spinning  object in the air fall".

Comment: @Bob D it is possible that this question is a duplicate of two questions,however it  wasn't mentioned if the spinning object was swung horizontally in the title of that question.